# Open Edx Third Party Login Integration with Keycloak

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, keycloak, python-social-auth, openedx

I am using edx-ironwood.2-6 in ubuntu 18.08. I am also running keycloak 9.0.0. To enable third-party login using Keycloak I am using the [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/keycloak.py) library suggested in [edx documentation](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_integrate_open/tpa_oauth.html). Since by default keycloak.py was not available in the edx-ironwood, I copied this keycloak.js file at the location

```
edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends
```

Followed all steps written in comments to setup keycloak and added following information in keycloak.py

```
    SECRET = 'client secret'
    PUBLIC_KEY = 'publick key from keycloak'
    AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token'
    USER_DETAILS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
```

Added following line in the lms.env.json

```
"THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_BACKENDS":[
     "social_core.backends.keycloak.KeycloakOAuth2",
     "social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2",
     "social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2"
]
```

In the Django Admin App, Added a Provider

```
Name: Keycloak
slug: keycloak
site: localhost:81
backend: keycloak
client Id: 'mooc'
Client Secret: 'secret key'
```

Also Added client secret in lms.auth.json

```
"SOCIAL_AUTH_OAUTH_SECRETS": {
    "keycloak":"14f89ef1-02ff-48ad-825f-8160e515ec8e"
 }
```

In Keycloak client settings, added access type 'confidential', and redirect uri 'http://localhost:81/auth/complete/keycloak/'

After server restart, In edx login page, login button for keycloak appearing but when I am clicking on it in the browser a message is coming *There has been a 500 error on the Open Edx Server*

In the apache2 log file following error is coming

```
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212377 2020] [:error] [pid 8143] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212419 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212442 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     response = get_response(request)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212462 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212485 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     response = self._get_response(request)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212506 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212526 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212548 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212569 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212589 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 185, in inner
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212610 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212630 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212651 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212671 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212697 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212720 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/views.py", line 23, in auth
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212742 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return do_auth(request.backend, redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212762 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/actions.py", line 29, in do_auth
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212783 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return backend.start()
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212803 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 35, in start
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212823 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return self.strategy.redirect(self.auth_url())
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212844 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/strategy.py", line 88, in redirect
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212864 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return redirect(url)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212884 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 56, in redirect
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212904 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212925 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 147, in resolve_url
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212945 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212965 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/src/django-wiki/wiki/models/__init__.py", line 90, in reverse
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.212986 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     url = original_django_reverse(*args, **kwargs)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.213006 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.213026 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.213047 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]   File "/opt/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.213067 2020] [:error] [pid 8143]     raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
[Sat Apr 18 17:09:21.213089 2020] [:error] [pid 8143] NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'None?scope=profile+email&state=yst8UI8KZihrluHg9R0oUFexFIx0QYGM&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81%2Fauth%2Fcomplete%2Fkeycloak%2F%3Fredirect_state%3Dyst8UI8KZihrluHg9R0oUFexFIx0QYGM&response_type=code&client_id=mooc' not found. 'None?scope=profile+email&state=yst8UI8KZihrluHg9R0oUFexFIx0QYGM&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81%2Fauth%2Fcomplete%2Fkeycloak%2F%3Fredirect_state%3Dyst8UI8KZihrluHg9R0oUFexFIx0QYGM&response_type=code&client_id=mooc' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I tried same third party integration with same python-social-auth for LinkedIn and that is working.

Since I am just a beginner in the Django, Can anyone help me identify the issue from the above details.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes @bvenkatr, Did some workaround and it worked. I am sharing the modified file which is based on open-id flow.

https://github.com/ranjeet692/python-social-auth-keycloak

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot, it's a long long pending task on that I was working on.

Comment: You are welcome, Venkat :)

Answer (score 1):

After finding and reading many official resources, I haven't found any solution which worked. So I decided to try my own custom file for keycloak.

Here is the link of the file
https://github.com/ranjeet692/python-social-auth-keycloak,

For open edx users, place this file into this directory
/edx-ironwood.2-6/apps/edx/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends

Follow the rest instruction as mentioned here
[Social Auth Documentation](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_integrate_open/tpa_oauth.html)

and restart the server. You should be able to login with keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an official backend for keycloak in python-social-auth:
https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/keycloak.py

Just add

```
"THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_BACKENDS": [
  "social_core.backends.keycloak.KeycloakOAuth2"
],
```

to your lms.env.json

together with the keycloak config:

```
"SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_KEY": "openedx",
"SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_SECRET": "...",
"SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_PUBLIC_KEY": "...",
"SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_AUTHORIZATION_URL": "https://YOUR_KEYCLOAK/realms/YOUR_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
"SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL": "https://YOUR_KEYCLOAK/realms/YOUR_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token",
```

Restart your installation, then go to:

https://YOUR.LMS/admin/third_party_auth/oauth2providerconfig/

and configure according to https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_integrate_open/tpa_oauth.html#additional-oauth2-providers-advanced